# REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Getting data from a list using rest API.
Here is my code ,

```
function getItems(url) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
            return data.d.results;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the function call,

```
var result = getItems("/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('LISTNAME')/Items?$select=ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3");
```

I am getting the items in console. But when trying to access '`result`' variable it showing *undefined*.  how can I return the result data. can i solve it by callback, promise or any other way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to learn all about the async nature of REST calls.

It is like when you order someone to get you a coffee:

> the request is Asynchronous; you do not get an immediate response

Your function getItems can not have a return value, as the Ajax request is still fetching your coffee.
That is why your getItems Function returns `undefined`

And your `return` in the success callback is **not** the return for getItems,
that return value goes nowhere, Callbacks can not return values

You have to learn the difference between (oldskool) CallBacks and (more powerfull) Promises
(*Note: in future JavaScript versions you will learn to use Generators/Async/Await*)

If you go with the Promises pattern you will do something like:

```
function getItems(url) {    
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

getItems( "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')/Items" ).done(function(data){
     data.d.results.forEach(function(item){  // no need for oldskool for loops
        console.log( item.ID, item.Title );
     });
});
```

also read: [REST call to get list not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165599/rest-call-to-get-list-not-working)

iREST

Comment: thanks for the Info. How to add return in my `getItems` function correctly?

Comment: You **can not** because the call is **asynchronous**, the above code shows how to return a **Promise** and then continue (.done) with the ``data`` when the Promise is resolved, see the last link for more code

Comment: This one is really a great example and good practice..

Answer (score 7):

There is one more way to implement. Please refer below code:

```
var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('LISTNAME')/Items?$select=ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3";

getItems(url).then(getItemsSuccess, getItemsFail);

function getItems(url){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

function getItemsSuccess(data){
    if(data.d.results.length > 0){
        console.log(data.d.results);
        var result = data.d.results; // set value of result variable 
    }
}

function getItemsFail(err){
    // error callback
}
```

Comment: this one also works...

Answer (score 5):

Try in this way:

```
function getItems(url,success) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
            success(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

and then just call the function like:

```
getItems('YOUR URL',function(data){
var result = data;
// Use 'result' variable
});
```

Callback function always works.