# Thumbnail/Image In Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, image

I am making a GET request on a list that contains images, but it is not returning the URL. I am attaching screenshots of one with a return and another environment that does not return. I have already deleted the list and created a new one, but the issue persists. I also noticed that when I upload with the name 'Test,' it changes the name, as shown in the screenshot.

code:

```
let items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('popUp').items.get();
```

Image:
[image]

Image Erro:
[image]

Comment: How are you creating the image column in the list, manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are dealing with two issues:

- When you make a GET request, the response might not be immediately available because the data is still being fetched. Therefore, the function call might return undefined. To handle this, you can use Promises or async/await:

```
async function getItems() {
    let items = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('popUp').items.get();
    console.log(items);
}

getItems();
```

- SharePoint might automatically modify the file name for various reasons. It could be due to invalid or restricted characters in the file name. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/why-has-my-filename-changed-f14307b4-e9ff-4cd9-be79-9524bb323744

See: [REST API call in SharePoint gets result, but when returns result becomes undefined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215456/rest-api-call-in-sharepoint-gets-result-but-when-returns-result-becomes-undefin)